# Making a good json with str.replace

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I noticed that if I put double quotes on my input boxes that get passed to php via json, json_decode will return null. Thus, I decided to replace double quotes with `\"` when making my json.

Thus, I have something like:

```
var valueToSet = input.replace(/"/gi, '\\"');
```

The code above replaces `""` with `\"` ... This works, and now I can input stuff like:

```
Hello hi "" " " " ' ' '' ' ' ' """
```

without breaking anything. However, if I input something like:

```
Hello hi "" \ "
```

it gets broken. How can I include to the above replace that slashes get also replaced? And what should I replace slashes with? with `\\` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about these issues. I think you're buiding your JSON by hand, while you should use a dedicated function that will take care of those details for you.

- YUI JavaScript library has a [JSON object](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/) with a `JSON.stringify` method that will work in all browsers and will use the native implementation if present.
- Newer browsers implement `JSON.stringify` (IE from version 8.0, Firefox from version 3.5, Chrome from version 4.0, Safari from version 4.0, Opera from version 10.5)
- Douglas Crockford, has written a [JSON library](http://www.json.org/)
- On the server side, PHP has [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- There is support for any other server side language, see [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for details

To answer your last question, yes, `\` should be replaced with `\\`, but again, it should be done by `json_encode`.

Comment: I've given you +1 because you're right; he should indeed be using an encoding function rather than trying to build it manually. However, you've given him the PHP answer, and he isn't asking about how to do it in PHP.

Comment: @Spudley, edited my answer and given you +1 since luquita is probably building JSON in JS. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Creating a JSON string in Javascript is typically done by creating the array or object you want to turn into JSON, and then running the `stringify()` method on it.

For example:

```
var myData = {....some stuff here....};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myData);
```

See this page on json.org for more info: http://www.json.org/js.html

However, note that JSON stringify and parse functionality is not available in all browsers. If you need to support older browsers, you may need to use a library to add this functionality. Libraries such as jQuery include JSON encoding functionality, and there are also stand-alone JSON libraries availble.